# Getting invalid characters in camel route exchange body()

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to read email content from a email "*.msg" file. But getting some invalid character, I have no idea what is this, please help me read email body content.

**Camel Route**

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(SOURCE_PATH).process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                final EmailResponseModel erm = new EmailResponseModel();
                erm.setEmail(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                exchange.getIn().setBody(erm, DBObject.class);
            }
        }).to(DESTINATION_PATH);
    }
```

**Invalid String in response of this line of code `exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)`**

```
��\u0011ࡱ\u001a�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

Comment: you probably can't use body directly. I recommand you to use a debugger to see how the body is made, to cast it properly

Comment: What you read from SOURCE_PATH may not be in pure text format. It may be binary content, and then you need to read it as byte[]. Or if its in some text format you need to know the encoding, eg UTF-8, iso-8859-1 or what it may be.

Comment: It is a email file (*.msg) file content, how should I read it ?